# Is there a way to retroactively debug an execution?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a suite of integration tests that are intermittently failing rarely enough that I can't debug them locally but often enough that my 400 test suite will often have 1 or two failures.

I use Intellij so I can "Run Until Failure", but that doesn't help me debug what's going on.

Is there a way to spit out some sort of debugging information on Exception that lets me do a mock run of the test under the exact conditions of the failure?  If not, is there another way to do this rather than just adding tons of logging and running the tests until one fails?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#exception-breakpoints

Comment: I need to debug things that have already happened.  If I can go backward from a breakpoint then that could help.

Comment: @b15 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-with-chronon.html

Comment: @crazycoder I'll accept that answer if you post it.  That's what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has support for [Chronon](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.2/debugging-with-chronon.html), the time-travelling debugger which may help in your case.

The last compatible IntelliJ IDEA version is [2019.2.4](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html).

[Chronon plug-in page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7403-chronon).

Comment: Fyi for others - this tool was great.  Don't be dissuaded by the reviews.  Just remember to add inclusions of namespaces and packages you want to be able to step into or see in your local variables as more than just an object of type x.

Comment: I can't ifnd anything about this plugin in jetbrains marketplace. Is this still valid?  The hyperlink simply takes me to the generic debugging help on jetbrains doc

Comment: @AdamHughes The last compatible IntelliJ IDEA version where this plug-in will work is 2019.2.4, you can get it at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html. Plug-in page: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7403-chronon. Help section for this version: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.2/debugging-with-chronon.html.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible. What would you do if you sent data over a network. You reach your breakpoint and then decide to go back. There is no way to *unsend* that data. Your software system will never be in the same state again.

You can have a look at the call hierarchy of your stack once you reach a breakpoint and determine places to insert new breakpoints though.

Also you can add.log statements in crucial places so you have some data when a breakpoint is activated. This way you see what happens before in the log.

Comment: That makes sense but I don't want have it execute again.  I just want to step through what it *did already*

Comment: I can't put breakpoints in code that's only failing one out of four hundred times.  Logging and rerunning is painful so this question is mostly to look for a better way.